# SQL Server date difference shows three digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running this below query gives the difference in minutes between two different regions.

```
DECLARE @Minute INT
SELECT @Minute = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
SELECT @Minute
```

[image]

I want to see only 2 first digits. How to get that?

Comment: "as we know minute is only of two digit". Do we know that? Why couldn't you have 300 minutes?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I mean to say 1 to 60 minutes its only 2 digits right?

Comment: But you have 330  minutes  .. could be 5 H and 30 min?

Comment: There are 60 minutes in an hour, yes. But there are more than 100 in 2 hours...

Comment: You say you want two digits, but the time difference is 330 minutes. How do you want to present that?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: maybe you mean to do DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()) % 60 that would give you difference between a time zone and 'whole hour' time zones

Comment: and  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()) / 60) to get hours

Comment: Can you be more specific, which 2 digits of 3 are needed?

Comment: @Serg First two digits.

Comment: `DECLARE @Minute INT; SELECT @Minute = ...whaterver but abs() <1000 ; IF (ABS(@minute)>=100) SET @Minute /= 10; SELECT @Minute;`

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially getting the time difference in minutes from UTC (Greenwich, England) and local time.

```
select GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE(), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())

2016-08-09 12:07:00.240     2016-08-09 07:07:00.237      -300      -5
```

I get -300 minutes, which is correct for Central Daylight Time - 5 hours.

It looks like you're in New Dehli, perhaps?  Or Sri Lanka?
[UTC+05:30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B05:30)

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
DECLARE @Minute INT
SELECT @Minute = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
SELECT @Minute

IF LEN(@Minute) >= 3
SET @Minute = LEFT(@Minute, LEN(@Minute) - 1)
SELECT @Minute
```

gives 33 instead of 330

Comment: And what does that value tell you?

Comment: What about time zones that are not at hour or half-hour offsets? E.g. Nepal?

Comment: @montewhizdoh, how is it correct? It's like saying `50 + 50 = 10` is correct.

Comment: "I want to see only 2 digits. How to get that?"

Comment: In that reasoning `SELECT 33` would also be correct.

Comment: not really, he says he wants the "first two digits". if the time changes @honeybadger, then your answer might be wrong sometimes. but even a broken clock is correct twice a day.

Comment: @montewhizdoh, It still makes no sense, if the value `25` is returned, what does that mean? It could be a time difference of 25 minutes, or 250 minutes, or 2500 minutes, or 25,5 minute. What's the point?

Comment: @honeybadger I know what you are saying, and I agree with you, and maybe the question is wrong, but I don't see him asking us that.